# View periodically changing event (Custom View) Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-view, android-custom-view, timertask

I am creating my custom view.
I have one question.
My view have to change periodically, for example change it's background or something else.
One question here it is possible to implement periodically changing event only using delayed task, timers and threads or maybe there is another way to do this, maybe platform has something already implemented in better way.

Another part of my question where should I put update logic ?
If there is no default implementation of periodically changing, I have to implement my own `Timer, ScheduledTaks` or something other (it doesn't really matter in this case). I have several ideas where can I put this

1. Put it directly into custom view and give user ability to control behavior from outside using attributes and methods of view.
2. Put it also into view but make it possible to user to set custom implementation, for example create and interface `PeriodicalBackgroundChanger` and method `setBackgroundChanger(...)` and let user provide it's own implementation
3. Or to doesn't do anything inside `View` but put all this stuff outside and just call methods of custom view like `setBackground`

What is the most correct and right way to implement this following all design patterns and "clean code" convention.

I will be grateful for anyone.

Thx in advance.

**EDIT**

To make question clearer.

I need to have simple `AutoSrollViewpager`. I know that there are completed implementations of such View, but they don't fit my needs.
And it is hard for me to say if I am performing animation inside view or on the view directly.
`ViewPager` has some implementation of pages inside it, so I need just to change them periodically. But on the other hand `ViewPager` nothing but combination of pages, so this question is a little bit abstract

Comment: Why not use broadcast receiver with alarm manager.

Comment: Are you performing some kind of animation in the `View`? If yes then I suggest you implement a completely custom Animation or move you update logic to the update listener of a `ValueAnimator`.